# Проблемы TestNG: после выполнения приложения продолжают крутиться тесты

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, testng

Проблема была замечена на уже готовом проекте, решил проверить на пустом проекте.

Есть проект, содержащий в себе один тестовый класс:

```
public class TestA {

@BeforeMethod
public void before(){
    System.out.println("Before."+Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@AfterMethod
public void after(){
    System.out.println("After."+Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@Test
public void test1 (){
    System.out.println("Test 1."+Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@Test
public void test2 (){
    System.out.println("Test 2."+Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@Test
public void test3 (){
    System.out.println("Test 3. -"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
}
}
```

Файл pom.xml следующий:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>123</groupId>
<artifactId>123</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Тесты запускаю в параллели с помощью testng.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="2" >
  <test name="Regression1">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestA">
        <methods>
          <include name="test1" />
          <include name="test2" />
          <include name="test3" />
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Regression2">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestA">
        <methods>
          <include name="test1" />
          <include name="test2" />
          <include name="test3" />
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

В результате получаю вот это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Такое чувство, что тест завис. Изменение версии testNG не меняет ситуацию. Кто нибудь сталкивался с похожей проблемой?
Если да, то подскажите, как решить!

запускаю через IDE (пкм(по testng.xml)->Run)(IDEA 15.0.4 [пробовал и на 17], java 1.8.0_121, TestNG 6.11). Windows 10 x64(с Windows 8.1 результат не поменлся)

Только что проверил на eclipse - все работает.
Проверил на ноутбуке(ubuntu 14) - не работает

Comment: а если запустить вне IDE?

Comment: мне нужно будет получать отчет от TestNG -в сгенерированном отчете он помечает эти тесты на провалившиеся

Comment: так вне IDE проблема повторяется или нет?

Comment: Вне IDE я вижу только логи, c логами все нормально (как и на скриншоте)

Comment: как именно вы запускаете? добавьте описание окружения.

Comment: запускаю через IDE (пкм(по testng.xml)->Run)(IDEA 15.0.4 [пробовал и на 17], java 1.8.0_121, TestNG 6.11)

Comment: укажите ОС и дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.